# How do I determine S/MIME encryption used?

Tags: encryption, email, smime

From what I understand it seems that S/MIME uses [PKCS #7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS) which can handle various different types of encryption. How is the choice of encryption method made by the e-mail client and how do I know what encryption was used for sent/received messages (e.g in Thunderbird)?

Answer (score 4):

Mail client encrypts message symmetrically with a random key. This key is then asymetrically encrypted with recipient's public key and attached to the message. Recipient then using his private key decrypts the symetric key and decrypts the content.

The symmetric algorithm used to encrypt the message can vary. I googled for this and it seems, that RC2 was used before and now it's TripleDES. The specific [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) is specified in the p7m file. Mail clients should have implemented both of them and I'm suer the modern ones use TripleDES. The asymmetric alhorithm for encrypting the key, according to [this rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2633), is Diffie-Hellman or RSA.

If you want to look inside the encrypted e-mail and you have the private key of recipient (you can send enc'd mail to yourself), look [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45222/smime-email-decryption-key-with-openssl). I asked for a way to display and interpret the p7m content. The bootom line is to use a tool called [dumpasn1](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epgut001/#standards).

Comment: There seems to be a command `asn1parse` in openssl now: `openssl smime -pk7out -in msg.eml | openssl asn1parse`, although dumpasn1 output look more structured.